# What kind of plant is this ?

Tags: identification

It looks like baby tears to me and the vague label said succulent on it. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not Solierolia, common name baby's tears - that is not a succulent plant. This one looks like it might be Peperomia rotundifolia, sometimes known as trailing jade plant. It likes high humidity and bright light - but preferably not direct sunlight. Getting the watering right is critical - this is a succulent plant with very small roots, and it  does not require much water, especially in winter, despite its requirement for high air humidity. Further information here https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/trailing-jade.html